# Using Kinect Gestures (.gbd) in Python

Tags: c#, python, database, kinect, gestures

I've been experimenting with the Microsoft Kinect (the one for Xbox One) and I have been making different, simple gestures using the Visual Gesture Builder. As a result, I have databases, .gbd files that are supposed to be used with C# to develop games and the like. My question is, I am more familiar with programming in Python than in C# (I have basic knowledge of C#) and I was wondering if there was a way to interface between the two so I can use/call those gesture databases in Python. I have no idea where to start. What tools should I use or is there a way to just import the different databases and can python read them? Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you looked into this *at all*?

Comment: A little bit. I found stuff on using python wrappers like Cython and OpenCV

Comment: Perhaps IronPython, a .NET implementation of Python (and the first hit for *"Python c#"*, so forgive me if I doubt your research skills) is something to consider?